# Ruby Regex filter based on two hashes

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to build a filter for logsatash. It needs to be in Ruby.
The filter takes metadata in json format and based on another json of allowed fields, it removes all non-matching fields from the metadata.
The main line of the filter is to make an evaluation. If the passed metadata name is in keys of the allowed hash it should evaluate to `true`. (All values of the allowed hash are `true` as in the example and don't matter).
In the allowed hash there can be a **glob** represented by a **wildcard** `*` in such case it can match any string.
For example `"instrument.network.*"` means that `"instrument.network.one"` or `"instrument.network.abc"` can pass.
But if there is no `*` like in `"event.type"` only such exact string can pass but **not** `"event.type.abc"`. In other words, the `*` represent any number of characters similarly as in regular expressions.
The simplified code looks like:

```
# input data
metadata = {"event.type"=>"message", "instrument.network.one"=>false, "instrument.network.two"=>false, "other.meta"=>true}
@allowed = {"timestamp"=>true, "event.type"=>true, "network.labels.*"=>true}

metadata.each do |key, val|
  # evaluation to be worked out
  evaluation = (@allowed.has_key? key)
  puts "the #{key} is allowed?: #{evaluation}"
  # metadata clearence
  metadata.delete(key) if !evaluation
end
puts "metadata after clearence: #{metadata}"
```

At the moment the output of this code is:

```
the event.type is allowed?: true
the instrument.network.one is allowed?: false
the instrument.network.two is allowed?: false
the other.meta is allowed?: false
metadata after clearence: {"event.type"=>"message"}
```

But I need to make the wildcard passing from `"network.labels.*"` to have output like:

```
the event.type is allowed?: true
the instrument.network.one is allowed?: true
the instrument.network.two is allowed?: true
the other.meta is allowed?: false
metadata after clearence: {"event.type"=>"message", "instrument.network.one"=>false, "instrument.network.two"=>false}
```

I am trying to use `Regexp.union(@allowed) =~ key` but can't make it work this way. I was trying other ruby tricks like `.find` etc, but don't have expected outcome. There are examples to use single regex, look in the array of string, but not another way around.
What would be Ruby way to build such a filter?

Comment: Your need to explain what `"network.labels.*"` means. (See the first sentence of my answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added an explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: In your edit you say, 'For example, `"network.labels.*"` means that `"network.labels.one"` or `"network.labels.abc"` can pass.' OK, but why does that mean that `"instrument.network.one"` or `"instrument.network.two"` will "pass", considering that both contain the additional string `"instrument."` and neither contain the string `"labels."`? Are you given `@allowed`, or can you change it to what I have in my answer?

Comment: The metadata hash contains more entries, but you right I should get more concise, edited the question.  I have given metadata and hash of allowed values and they need to pass in exact form. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `@allowed` should be as follows. If the last key does not begin with "instrument." or ".labels" is present, the purpose of the wildcard "*" is not clear.

```
@allowed = { "timestamp"=>true, "event.type"=>true,
             "instrument.network.*"=>true }

arr = @allowed.map { |k,_|
  Regexp.new(k.gsub('.', '\.').sub('*', '.*')) }
  #=> [/timestamp/, /event\.type/, /instrument\.network\..*/] 
r = /\A#{Regexp.union(arr)}\z/
  #=> /\A(?-mix:(?-mix:timestamp)|(?-mix:event\.type)|(?-mix:instrument\.network\..*))\z/ 
metadata.select do |k,_|
  res = k.match?(r)
  puts "#{k} is allowed?: #{res}"
  res
end
event.type is allowed?: true
instrument.network.one is allowed?: true
instrument.network.two is allowed?: true
other.meta is allowed?: false
  #=> {"event.type"=>"message", "instrument.network.one"=>false, ] 
  #    "instrument.network.two"=>false}
```